# await does not call Promise.then method in Node version > 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise, instrumentation

The `await` keyword calls the `Promise.then` method in NodeJS <= v10 but this behavior is not observed in v12 or v14  or higher. I want a trap/hook for then `.then` method that gets invoked irrespective of `await` or explicit `.then` style callbacks. I was able to achieve this in Node <= 10 but does not work in Node 12 or 14 (randomly chosen). Am I doing something wrong?

```
➜  Desktop cat test.js

async function func() {
  const aPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => { resolve(123); }, 100);
  });

  const clone = Object.create(aPromise);
  const _then = Object.getPrototypeOf(clone).then;
  _then.bind(aPromise);

  aPromise.then = function () {
    console.log('then called');
    return _then.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  const result = await aPromise;
  console.log('Log:', result);
}

func();%

➜  Desktop
➜  Desktop nvm use 10
Now using node v10.19.0 (npm v6.13.4)
➜  Desktop
➜  Desktop
➜  Desktop node test.js
then called
Log: 123
➜  Desktop
➜  Desktop
➜  Desktop nvm use 12
Now using node v12.18.4 (npm v6.14.6)
➜  Desktop
➜  Desktop
➜  Desktop node test.js
Log: 123
➜  Desktop
➜  Desktop
➜  Desktop nvm use 14
Now using node v14.12.0 (npm v6.14.8)
➜  Desktop
➜  Desktop
➜  Desktop node test.js
Log: 123
➜  Desktop
```

Answer (score 3):

There was as normative change to the spec in how `await` handles promises created via the built-in `Promise` constructor that allowed optimization. If you want to hook into the addition of handlers to the promise, you can use a subclass to do that:

```
class MyPromise extends Promise {
    then(onFulfilled, onRejected) {
        console.log("then called");
        return super.then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
    }
}
async function func() {
    const aPromise = new MyPromise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => { resolve(123); }, 100);
    });
  
    const result = await aPromise;
    console.log("Log:", result);
}
func();
```

That works even on version of V8 with the optimization (for instance, Node.js v14):

```
then called
Log: 123
```

If you need to do this with a promise you've received rather than created, you can create an instance of your own `Promise` subclass and resolve it to that other promise using the static `resolve` method of your subclass:

```
class MyPromise extends Promise {
    then(onFulfilled, onRejected) {
        console.log("then called");
        return super.then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
    }
}
async function func() {
    // I'm creating it here, but this is to simulate having gotten
    // a promise from somewhere you don't control
    const aPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => { resolve(123); }, 100);
    });

    // Create an instance of your subclass and resolve it to the other promise
    const result = await MyPromise.resolve(aPromise);
    console.log('Log:', result);
}
func();
```

That also shows:

```
then called
Log: 123
```